# Unable to detect second display via HDMI with NVIDIA X Server Settings?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Under bumblebee I was able to run nvidia-settings. I have two dell monitors which on win7 I am able to use by using one via VGA and the other via HDMI. In ubuntu, I can only use one with VGA as nothing happens when I plug in the other one via HDMI even doing detect displays in nvidia-settings. How can I get it to be detected? Here are some screenshots of my nvidia-settings:

[image: X Server Display Configuration]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You tried to access "Display" from the menu ?
Some times in Nvidia X Server doesn't appear both displays.
Or try to reboot with botj monitors plug in and then acces Nvidia X Server again or Display from the menu.